# I've generated early bound entity classes for Dynamics CRM 2011 with CrmSvcUtil - now what?

Tags: c#, sdk, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have setup a test Dynamics CRM 2011 server.

I've used the SDK's CrmSvcUtil utility to generate the early bound entity classes (e.g. mycrm.cs).

I've created a new project in Visual Studio and added references to Microsoft.CRM.SDK.Proxy, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, and System.Runtime.Serialization.

I've also added the mycrm.cs file to my project as an existing file.

Now what?

I know, I know...read the SDK. I've tried:

[Using the Early Bound Entity Classes in Code](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328210.aspx)

[Using the Early Bound Entity Classes for Create, Update, Delete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328499.aspx)

[Create Early Bound Entity Classes with the Code Generation Tool (CrmSvcUtil.exe)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx)

Call me an idiot if you must - I'm sure these articles probably include the info. I need, but I'm not seeing it. Help!

Comment: What is the problem? What you wanna do? All communication with Dynamics based on its services, all you could do is to call it methods from solution. Another way to extend CRM is to create packages from UI with custom entities or groups or whatever.

Comment: I want to perform CRUD operations on my CRM. I have an independent internet facing application and I want to sync info. from this app. into Dynamics CRM.

Comment: Have you connected to *OrganizationService*? Can you obtain from this services any thing?

Comment: No, but I haven't been able to find code for this, only for OrganizationServiceProxy.

Comment: Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328029.aspx?

Comment: This looks good, thanks. I'll see if this resolves my issues.

Comment: @user854301 - So, in the reference you gave me above there is a line:

Console.Write("{0} {1} created, ", account.LogicalName, account.Name)

But when I attempt to enter this in a new project it wants me to enter account.EntityLogicalName instead of just account.LogicalName, is there a reference I need to add to the project?

Comment: If you are wanting to use earlybound entities, checkout the EarlyBoundGenerator for the XrmToolBox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to connect to CRM web service:

```
OrganizationServiceProxy orgserv;
ClientCredentials clientCreds = new ClientCredentials();
ClientCredentials devCreds = new ClientCredentials();


clientCreds.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "user";
clientCreds.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "P@$$w0rd";
clientCreds.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "myDomain";
IServiceConfiguration<IOrganizationService> orgConfigInfo =
            ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(new Uri("https://myCRMServer/myOrg/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"));

orgserv = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgConfigInfo, clientCreds);
orgserv.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());
```

After that, you are going to use your XrmServiceContext, or how you name it here:

> CrmSvcUtil.exe
>   /url:http://servername/organizationname/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
>       /out:.cs /username: /password: /domain:
>       /namespace: /serviceContextName:**XrmServiceContext**

Then you can start with CRUD examples from [link you posted](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328499.aspx) :)

Example for updating contact:

```
using(var context = new XrmServiceContext(orgserv))
{
    Contact con = context.contactSet.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Test Contact");
    if(con != null)
    {
        con.City = "NY";

        context.UpdateObject(con);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)